# How can I check if an anchor account was closed

Tags: anchor

I was watching [Will's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hb__mykwRdA&list=PLilwLeBwGuK5wQcYtXpPKwKXguxzgrnrJ) on program security and he mentioned that there is a field on Anchor that you can check on whether an account was closed and reopened.

What field is this?

Answer (score 5):

Anchor used to set the account data to `CLOSED_ACCOUNT_DISCRIMINATOR` for closed accounts before version `0.26.0` which was equal to `&[0xff; 8]`.

The close logic has been replaced after the introduction of `realloc` feature and the `close` constraint now uses `realloc` to zero the account data instead.

[PR](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/2169)